# Slowing down a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have an $n \times n$ rotation matrix, $R$. If we imagine the point, $x = (1,0,0, \dots)$ on the unit sphere, applying the rotation matrix to this point will move it elsewhere on the sphere, say to point $x'$. Now, think of a line along the surface of the sphere, connecting $x$ with $x'$ (shortest path between them). I'd like to get a rotation matrix, $R_f$ that takes me a fraction $f$ of the way along this line. Is there a general algorithm to get $R_f$?

Comment: Any rotation can be written as $R=\exp (\theta M)$ where $M$ is antisymmetric. The matrix $\exp (\theta / f M)$ will do what you want.

Comment: @lcv ,${\theta \over f}M$

Comment: Interesting. How do I find the $\theta$ and $M$ though? I'm just given $R$.

Comment: Essentially what you're trying to do is $R^{1/f}$ which is $= \exp(\ln (R)/f)$. However some care must be taken because the matrix log is not always defined (also the standard log). A popular choice is the principal log.

Comment: how do you define a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @CroCo - all points that are a unit distance from the origin?

Comment: A unit circle satisfies this as well, right? Is the circle a sphere?

Comment: Yes, it is a sphere is 2-d space.

Answer (score 2):

When we Multiply by the rotation Matrix $R$ , we are rotating the Points , Point $x$ moves by $\theta$ , the angle of rotation.

When we Multiply by rotation Matrix $R$ twice , we are Mutilpying by Matrix $R^2$ , we are rotating twice , Point $x$ moves by $2\theta$.

Thus $R^n$ will move by $n\theta$

When we want Pont $x$ to move by lesser angle , we have to make $n$ lesser.

Thus , $R^{0.5}$ will move by $0.5\theta$
Multiply twice will give $R^{0.5} R^{0.5} = R^{1}$ , which will move by $0.5\theta+0.5\theta=1\theta$

Powers of Matrix $R$ can be Evaluated to move by fractional angle values $1/3,1/4,3/4,2/3$ Etc.

That Evaluation will be not hard when $R$ is given in terms of $\theta$.
Otherwise , we have to make Cumbersome Calculations involving Inverse & such.

UPDATE :
Numerically getting the fractional Powers is Cumbersome with Matrix Calculations.
It will be easier with trigonometry :

2D Example : With trigonometry , let given R be like this :
[image: 2D]
Here it is Simple to plug-in $\theta$ , including fractional values , to generate the wanted rotation Matrix with elementary trigonometry.

3D Example : Let given R by like this :
[image: 3D]

We have to get the Original Angle Details , which can be done with Cumbersome Calculations given here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Independent_planes
We then have to make $R$ in terms of the angles we got , then plug-in the wanted new $\theta$ fractional values.
This is not recommended, better to go with the Matrix in terms of $\theta$ , where we use trigonometry.

Details :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Thanks. How do we raise the rotation matrix to a fractional power in general?

Comment: (1) In general , Matrix to fractional Power is very hard (2) Rotation Matrix to fractional Power is somewhat easier : We have to Decompose given matrix into the rotation angle values , then use the wanted angles. (3) Easiest is when we generate the rotation matrix with rotation angles itself & then plug-in the wanted angles. (4) Check out [[ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html ]] It has a lot there.

Comment: Not sure why you say going with a general matrix is not recommended. One can simply diagonalize it and raise the diagonals to the $\frac{1}{n}$ power. Easy peasy.

Comment: When you Diagonalize , you will not have the rotation matrix , @RohitPandey , you will have a scaling matrix. You can check with known rotation matrix : Diagonalized matrix will not rotate & It will give scaled output. The Powers will then not rotate too.

Comment: If you diagonalize and multiply the $PDP^{-1}$ you obviously have a rotation matrix (because it's just the original matrix). $PD^2P^{-1}$ is also a rotation matrix. Are you saying that $PD^{.5}P^{-1}$ is not a rotation matrix?

Comment: In your Earlier Comment you gave $D$ & $D^{1/n}$ , Hence I said these are not rotations. Now that you give $PDP^{-1}$ , YES , that will give a rotation. It is "Spectral Decomposition" , which is not very easy to Evaluate. When using Software Packages , that Difficulty is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The generator for the $1-d$ abelian subgroup of the orthogonal goup SO(3) in a plane is the linear combination of the three generators for the three axes

$$(L_i)_{j,k}   == \varepsilon_{i j k}$$

These are the three antisymmetric 0-matrices with a $\pm 1$ on the index pair other than the axis

$$
L_3  =l_{1,2}=
\left(
\begin{array}
\\ \ 0,1,0
\\-1,0,0
\\ \ \ 0,0,0 
\end{array}
  \right)  , \ \ \ 
L_3^2  = l_{1,2}^2=
\left(
\begin{array}
\\ -1,\ 0,0
\\  0,-1,0
\\ \ \ 0,\  0,0 
\end{array}\right)$$

Consequently the exponential power series generates the group of rotations in the 1-2 plane

$$O(1,2,\phi)=
e^{\phi *   \left(
\begin{array}
\\ \ 0,1,0
\\-1,0,0
\\ \ \ 0,0,0 
\end{array}
  \right)} \  = \ \left(
\begin{array}
\\ \ \cos \phi,\sin \phi,0
\\-\sin\phi,cos \phi,0
\\ \ \ 0,0,1 
\end{array}
  \right)$$

Addition of small rotations is linear as everything in analyis. So the receipt is, take the linear combinations of the unit vector repesenting the axis. This is the cross product of the two unit vectors to the two points with the three generators for the three planes.

$$ O(\vec p , \vec q, \phi) = e^{ \frac{\phi}{2}  \sum_{i,j} l_{i,j} \ p_i q_j} $$

There is an ambiguity in the signs, that reflects itself in the determinant. To exclude mirror transformation, the result has to be the unit matrix for $\phi=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to do a Jordan decomposition of $R$ to $QJQ^T$ where $Q$ is orthogonal, $J$ is block diagonal composed of $2\times2$ orthogonal matrices. $2\times 2$ orthogonal can easily be written as the exponential of skew symmetric, thus $J$ can be written as $e^{A}$, and $R=Qe^{A}Q^T=e^{QAQ^T}$.

**There is another approach**, which is much simpler, but it does not interpolate at a "constant speed". This is to use the [Cayley-Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform), to create a skew symmetric matrix $A=(R-I) (R+I)^{-1}$ and then interpolate $R(t)=(I-tA)(I+tA)^{-1}$. setting $t=0$ obtains the unity $I$ and $t=1$ the original rotation $R$ and for $t\in(0,1)$ you get a smooth family of rotations between $I$ and $R$.

I stress again that the $t$ parameter is not and angle, so the interpolation is not a constant rotation. I believe that in computer vision this is also called a "slerp" (spherical linear interpolation).